# Can I switch between Jekyll themes on a mouse click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jekyll

I am building my website using a Jekyll theme. The basic website is up and running. However, I wanted to provide an option on the UI to change the theme. Is it possible to add a button such that a mouse click on it changes the theme?

Expanding on what I'm asking, Jekyll generates static pages. Is it possible to re-trigger Jekyll  from the webpage itself to generate pages with a new `_layout` and `_sass`?

One possible approach might be to keep the two themes in different branches, and then change the `Github pages publishing source` to the new branch. Is this approach possible? Or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this approach is not possible - if the click would run the generator, it would no longer be a static page.

What you can do is

- do the switch on the client side with js, swapping paths to css files or something
- generate all pages with both themes, and have the button link to the respective other.